# ELV fixtures with Lutron Caseta

Tags: electrical, led

I've been planning on adding a couple Lutron Caseta switches to my place and while planning I've identified 2 specific fixtures that may or may not be an issue.

One of them is the bathroom vanity fixture of which the manufacturer has recommended its use with an ELV dimmer, however I do not intend to dim it and merely only want it to turn on and off. Would using this SKU accomplish what I need? "PD-6ANS" (has neutral wire) or is there something I am missing that would still require an ELV dimmer regardless?

The second one is the kitchen under cabinet lighting, I'm having a hard time finding where the transformer is located but from the previous owner's files I was able to find that it is using a dimmable transformer paired with dimmable LED's, would it typically still require and ELV dimmer or can I simply use the PD-6ANS as well as I do not need it to dim?

PD-6ANS spec sheet: https://webapiaw1proddat01st01.blob.core.windows.net/assets/documents/369831_ENG.pdf

Comment: Including links to the PD-6ANS documentation would be very helpful to those who may be able to answer your question (i.e. help them help you).

Answer (score 1):

So the normal Lutron Caseta dimmer switch did indeed give me a lot of buzzing issues and I considered purchasing the ELV model to try but in the end since I did not need the dimming function I opted to skip the ELV model  and purchased another switch that is only ON/OFF which also required a neutral wire connection. SKU# PD-5ANS-WH-RC.

This one did not give me any buzzing noises at the switch or light fixture.